# Execute script/gpo via Microsoft VPN

Tags: vpn, group-policy, microsoft-office-365

I've put together a small script to install a piece of software that will help us in migrating to Office 365.

It's successfully deployed to majority of the hard wired/wireless domain connected workstations/laptops via Group Policy, within Startup/Shutdown also Logon/Logout.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET WORKINGDIR=%~dp0

START /WAIT MSIEXEC.exe /I "%WORKINGDIR%outlookassistant.msi" ORGANIZATIONKEY="123456789" /QN /L+ "\\SERVER\ITSupport\Logs\SK\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt"

IF EXIST "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)" (GOTO 1) ELSE (GOTO 2)

:1
START /WAIT MSIEXEC.exe /I "%WORKINGDIR%mapi64helper.msi" /QN /L+ "\\SERVER\ITSupport\Logs\SK\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt"
START /WAIT MSIEXEC.exe /I "%WORKINGDIR%sklquery_x64.msi" /QN /L+ "\\SERVER\ITSupport\Logs\SK\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt"

:2
START /WAIT MSIEXEC.exe /I "%WORKINGDIR%sklquery_x86.msi" /QN /L+ "\\SERVER\ITSupport\Logs\SK\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt"

EXIT
```

But, I'm having real issues targeting those connecting via Microsoft VPN.

Any ideas on getting this script to run when a user has connected to our Microsoft VPN? I've tweaked policy processing on slow connections, still no luck.

My thinking is that maybe whilst connected to VPN then performing a log out, the script would process.

Thanks

Comment: By Microsoft VPN I assume you are saying remote domain joined machines connect to the network through RRAS. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work the computer must be joined to the domain, the user that is authenticating to the Windows computer (not the VPN) must be a domain user, and the Windows computer when it is connected to the VPN must be able to contact at least one domain controller.

To test, I suggest taking a domain joined laptop, connecting it to a different network, logging in with a domain user (the credentials will have to be cached on the domain joined computer), connecting to the VPN and running `gpupdate /force`. If it doesn't work then check if there are errors in the log file.